# texture fill doesn't display in ArcScene

Tags: polygon, arcscene, terrain, display, 2d

My texture fill doesn't display properly in ArcScene but it does in ArcMap. What am I doing wrong? Help!

ArcMap:

[image: ArcMap]

ArcScene:

[image: ArScene]

The same texture fill has been selected in both ArcMap and ArcScene. Why does one show up and the other get blotted out?